# Which RAM stick to pick?

Tags: memory

Please don't confuse this question with a 2x2GB or 4GB.

I have 2 RAM sticks that are shown side by side in the two photos. Both are from different manufacturers, but both have the same capacity (1GB). I can only pick one of them, so which RAM do I pick?

I have a tall one (on the left side of the 2 photos) and a short one (on the right side).

To find the short one Google *Kingston KVR*. The tall one is just a normal RAM that every desktop has.

[image: Kingston KVR RAM]
[image: Normal Ram]
<sup>**front/back views of 2 1GB RAM sticks**  (Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Look up the model numbers, compare the specifications, check your mainboard manual...

Comment: Checked. Got nothing there. Anyway I lost my model number. And also, just another question: will 3GB be better than 2GB? It feels like 2GB is faster than 3GB in my computer.

Comment: Your question is currently closed because it is unclear what you are asking. I am taking a wild guess and assuming that you have a motherboard with only two sockets for memory modules; that one of these is filled with a 2GiB DIMM ad that you have two more 1GiB DIMMs on your desk. You can only place one of them and want to know which one. If that is the case then please edit your question to state this.

3GiB is almost always faster than 2GiB.

Answer (score 3):

Both the Kingston RAM stick and the Kingmax RAM stick are low-priced, budget RAM, and both RAM sticks are old. The tall RAM stick was manufactured in 2009, and the short RAM stick doesn't have a sticker on it showing when it was manufactured.

An old budget RAM stick may be faulty, so try both RAM sticks one at a time, and run Memtest86. [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) boots from a USB flash drive or CD and tests the RAM in your computer for faults using a series of comprehensive algorithms and test patterns. Memtest86 is also built-in in many Linux distributions. Choose the RAM stick that has the least errors in the results of Memtest86. If both RAM sticks have errors, you may prefer to buy a new RAM stick, however with old RAM you may have to pay more than it's worth to get a new replacement RAM stick for your old computer.

Comment: _"Choose the RAM stick that has the least errors"_ - do not use a stick that shows errors at all.

Comment: ... which you then proceed to dump in the trash, not stick in a machine. At least, if you care about data integrity and machine stability. Also, I wouldn't really consider Kingston to be a budget brand for consumer PC memory.

Comment: `memtest` takes time. Anyway I'll try.

Comment: Kingston calls their products "value RAM" instead of "budget RAM", but I don't buy it, because if the RAM was high quality, then Kingston wouldn't need to mess around by using phrases like "value RAM" to describe it. "value RAM" makes it sound to the consumer like the RAM is valuable like an expensive, high-end smartphone.

Comment: If both sticks show zero errors, I think the short one is cuter.

Answer (score 0):

You should test each stick (using memtest or equivalent) to make sure it works 100%.

If only 1 works, use that one.

If both work individually, try both together.    If they both work together, use both of them - 3 Gigs will give better performance then 2 gigs.

If either one works, but not both together, consider the case, and look at airflow considerations - this should not be a major consideration though.

Kingston is a more reputable brand then Kingmax, and the smaller stick will be made with better technology but to be honest, from the pictures, both RAM sticks look like they have been abused.